# Strange font rendering when using Tahoma

Tags: fonts

When using tahoma (antialias off), I get something like this:

Any idea?

[image]

(see bookmarks, computer and networks 'bold' in left panel)
Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install the bold version of Tahoma as well. You seem to have installed only the regular font.